# On the expectation operator for stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value

As I've understood it

[image]

But I'm having difficulties with framing this definition with the general one given for stochastic processes. Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$, and a measurable space $S$, a stochastic process $X(t, \omega)$ is a set of time-dependent $S$-valued random variables. If the probability distribution of this process has density, and we assume $S=\mathbb{R}$, then
$$\tag{1} \mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} xp(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$
**Where is the $\omega$ dependence** (in the screenshot above $s=\omega$, so $v(t,s)=x(t,\omega)$) **?**. It's as if $\Omega\equiv S$, but is it true/possible? The sample space (the total "number" of possible paths) has nothing to deal with the measurable space which the "samples" (paths) take value on...

Comment: Formula (1) looks wrong, not because $\omega$ doesn't explicitly appear (the density compensates for that), but because it should be $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\cdot p(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring could you please tell me how precisely it compensates? I often see notations like $P(\mathrm{d}\omega)=p(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$, but I can’t give an intuitive meaning to $\mathrm{d}\omega$.

Comment: The statement $P(d\omega) = p(x,t)\,dx$ is abuse of notation to a criminal level.  Dropping the $t$ for simplicity, it represents $$\int_\Omega X(\omega)\,P(d\omega) = \int_\mathbb{R} x p(x)\,dx$$ whenever $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $P$-measurable random variable.  Note that many more parts of that equation change than just what is in the notation you referenced.  As for the $d\omega$ part of $P(d\omega)$, this makes more sense when $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, but more formally I'd argue $P(d\omega)$ should be written $dP(\omega)$.

Comment: Either $P(d\omega)$ or $dP(\omega)$ is broadly accepted, though.  See for instance the [wikipedia entry on measure-theoretic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Measurable_functions)

Comment: Ok, but what does it mean that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$? That there are uncountably many samples, but how can I tell that they can be all gathered in some (which one?) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: The set $\Omega$ is just a fixed set.  My point is that when $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathrm{d}\omega$ looks just like $\mathrm{d}x$.  When $\Omega$ is an arbitrary set, this interpretation of $\mathrm{d}\omega$ may not make sense, but people will still use it.  In contrast, $\mathrm{P}$, being a measure, we can always make sense of $\mathrm{dP}(\omega)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks for looking after this. I believe OP's riddle can be clarified by the hint that equation (1) is a sound simple consequence of the fact that the *distribution* of $X$ ($\mathbb R^n$-*valued* function on some *domain* $\Omega$ having nothing to do with $\mathbb R^n$)  is defined as the [push forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $P$ by $X$. Eq. (1) then says that this push forward measure has density $p(x,t)$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So the distribution of a random process allows us to pass from a Lebegue measure (for instance) to a probability measure on Ω
 but if you read the equation written by @BrianMoehring left to right, it's telling the opposite. So... what is that? A push-backwards? How is it defined?

Comment: The distribution of a random variable is a measure on the space that r.v. takes its values in ($\mathbb R^n$ in the above case). If I tell you only a distribution it won't allow you to pass to a probability measure on $\Omega\,.$ Concrete: many r.v.s can be normally distributed (as we know). This does not mean we know anything about $(\Omega,{\cal F},P,X)$ that realises those distributions. Recommendation: digest what a pushforward measure is and move on.

Comment: I think I've understood something, maybe.. Is \begin{equation}
    \mu_t(B)=\int_{X^{-1}(B)}\mathrm{d}\mathrm{P}(\omega)=\int_Bp(x,t)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation} correct ($B$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Lebesgue measure, $\mu$ is the distribution and $p$ is the probability density)?

Comment: That's correct.